# Php file not displaying data collected from html file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to link a simple html file with a php file.The data from the html file is properly getting transferred to php file , but while displaying that data through php file nothing is gets displayed on the browser.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <header align ="center"><i><b><font size="30">Calculator</font></b></i></header>

        <form action="result.php" method="POST" >
            <br>
            <br>
            Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1">
            <br><br>
            Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2">    
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body align="center">
        <header align ="center"><i><b><font size="30">RESULT</font></b></i></header>
        <?
            $var1= $_POST['number1'];
            $var2= $_POST['number2'];
            echo $var1;
            echo $var2;
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `Method = GET` in your html but You're using `$_POST` in your php file

Comment: what are you doing? two <html> tags? you use get and want to access POST Requests? hint, try to understand html and server-client communication first

Comment: Sorry for that,i was trying it with POST only but i forgot to make the change in here while posting.
Any other issue other than the POST one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="result.php" method="GET" >
```

you are using GET and receiving as POST

```
    $var1= $_POST['number1'];
    $var2= $_POST['number2'];
```

you change either one of them, but my advice would be to change your form action to:

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST" >
```

Comment: This answer is correct, however, if you'd like to use GET anyway for some reason, you can use $_GET['number1'] , or even use $_REQUEST['number1'] to get any request.

Answer (score 0):

You're are using `method` as `GET` in your source file but getting as `$_POST` in the destination file.

You should use `method="POST"` from your source file.

So, It should have something like

`<form action="result.php" method="POST" >`

Learn more about Sending [data from Form Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the data is beign transfered? Try this as it seems that you are using GET instead of post, then use the proper one:

```
<?
   echo 'POST: ';
   var_dump($_POST);
   echo 'GET: ';
   var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this:

```
 <form action="result.php" method="GET" >
```

you should either do:

```
 $var1= $_GET['number1'];
 $var2= $_GET['number2'];
```

or change

```
 <form action="result.php" method="POST" >
```

(which is anyway recommended ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <header align ="center"><i><b><font size="30">RESULT</font></b></i></header>
    <?php
        $var1= $_GET['number1'];
        $var2= $_GET['number2'];
        echo $var1;
        echo $var2;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```